# How to set the size of an array via an InputBox? c#

Tags: c#, size, inputbox

How can I set the size of an array via an InputBox(referenced from VisualBasic) in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this one ?

```
 var size = Interaction.InputBox("Enter the array size:");
 int arraySize;
 if (int.TryParse(size, out arraySize))
 {
      var myArray = new int[arraySize];
 }
```